# How can I center THREE.points (text mesh) in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, svg, three.js, centering

I made vertices using svg path. And I made a text mesh using these vertices.

But the text mesh is not centered. The starting position of a letter is always the same, regardless of the length of the letter.

I always want to see the middle of the text.
If the length of the text is long, the entire text should be displayed on the screen.

How can I solve this problem? Please help me T.T...

The following are gif files that show the current situation.

[When I write "hello"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5mEv.gif)

[When I write "hello world"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHX1H.gif)

```
import * as THREE from "three";
import { OrbitControls } from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls";
import { FontLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/FontLoader";
import { TextGeometry } from "three/examples/jsm/geometries/TextGeometry";

import { ALPHAMAP } from "../constants/url";

import { load } from "opentype.js";
import UnDotumBold from "../../assets/UnDotumBold.ttf";

class WebGLCanvas {
  constructor(canvas) {
    this._canvas = canvas;
    this._clock = new THREE.Clock();
    this._count = 4000;
    this._distance = 2;
    this._mouseX = 0;
    this._mouseY = 0;

    this._vertexShader = document.querySelector("#vertex-shader").textContent;
    this._fragmentShader =
      document.querySelector("#fragment-shader").textContent;
  }

  async _setupTextModel() {
    const font = await load(UnDotumBold);

    //  I created a svg and got the svg paths to create vertices.
    const svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
    const g = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g");
    svg.setAttribute("viewBox", [0, 0, 1920, 1920].join(" "));
    g.setAttribute("fill", "black");

    let pathMarkup = "";
    const fontPaths = font.getPaths(text, 0, 1000, 1000);

    fontPaths.forEach((fontPath) => {
      const path = fontPath.toSVG();

      pathMarkup += path;
    });
    g.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", pathMarkup);

    document.body.appendChild(svg);
    svg.appendChild(g);

    const paths = svg.querySelectorAll("path");
    const svgViewBoxWidth = svg.viewBox.baseVal.width;
    const svgViewBoxHeight = svg.viewBox.baseVal.height;

    svg.remove();

    //  vertices
    this._textVertices = [];
    const colors = [];
    const sizes = [];
    const delay = 1;
    const gradient = chroma.scale([
      "ef476f",
      "ffd166",
      "06d6a0",
      "118ab2",
      "073b4c",
    ]);
    const colorRGB = {
      r: Math.random() * 100,
      g: Math.random() * 100,
      b: Math.random() * 100,
    };
    const positionXYZ = {
      x: Math.random() * 3000,
      y: Math.random() * 3000,
      z: Math.random() * 3000,
    };

    const timeline = gsap.timeline({
      onReverseComplete: () => {
        timeline.timeScale(1);
        timeline.play(0);
      },
    });

    paths.forEach((path) => {
      const length = path.getTotalLength();

      for (let i = 0; i < length; i += 30) {
        const pointLength = i;
        const point = path.getPointAtLength(pointLength);

        //  end point ❗❗ => I think this part is the problem..
        const vector = new THREE.Vector3(
          point.x - svgViewBoxWidth / 2,
          -point.y + svgViewBoxHeight / 2,
          (Math.random() - 0.5) * 15,
        );

        //  start point
        const start = new THREE.Vector3(
          vector.x + (Math.random() - 0.5) * positionXYZ.x,
          vector.y + (Math.random() - 0.5) * positionXYZ.y,
          vector.z + (Math.random() - 0.5) * positionXYZ.z,
        );

        const coloursX =
          point.x / svgViewBoxWidth + (Math.random() - 0.5) * 0.2;
        const color = gradient(coloursX).rgb();

        this._textVertices.push(vector);

        vector.r = 1 - (vector.z + 7.5) / colorRGB.r;
        vector.g = 1 - (vector.z + 7.5) / colorRGB.g;
        vector.b = 1 - (vector.z + 7.5) / colorRGB.b;

        timeline.from(
          vector,
          {
            x: start.x,
            y: start.y,
            z: start.z,
            r: color[0] / 255,
            g: color[1] / 255,
            b: color[2] / 255,
            duration: "random(0.5, 1.5)",
            ease: "power2.out",
          },
          delay * 0.0012,
        );

        sizes.push(25 * this.renderer.getPixelRatio());
      }
    });

    //  text mesh
    this._textGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(
      this._textVertices,
    );

    this._textGeometry.setAttribute(
      "color",
      new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(colors, 3),
    );
    this._textGeometry.setAttribute(
      "size",
      new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(sizes, 1),
    );

    const textMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
      uniforms: {
        pointTexture: {
          value: new THREE.TextureLoader().load(ALPHAMAP.CIRCLE),
        },
      },
      vertexShader: this._vertexShader,
      fragmentShader: this._fragmentShader,
      transparent: true,
      depthTest: false,
    });

    this._textMesh = new THREE.Points(this._textGeometry, textMaterial);
    this._textMesh.scale.set(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
    // this._textMesh.geometry.center(); => ❌ It dosen't work..

    // this._getCenterPoint(this._textMesh); => ❌ It dosen't work..

    this._textGroup = new THREE.Group();
    this._textGroup.add(this._textMesh);
    this._textGroup.position.set(0, 0, -240);

    this._init();
  }

  /*
  _getCenterPoint(mesh) {
    const { geometry } = mesh;
    const center = new THREE.Vector3();

    geometry.computeBoundingBox();
    geometry.boundingBox.getCenter(center);

    mesh.localToWorld(center);
    return center;
  }
  */

  _init() {
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();

    this._sizes = {
      width: window.innerWidth,
      height: window.innerHeight,
    };

    this._setupCamera(this._sizes);
    this._setupControls(this.camera, this._canvas);
    this._render(this._canvas, this._sizes);

    this._tick(this._sizes);

    window.addEventListener("resize", this._resize);
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", this._mousemove.bind(this));
  }

  _setupCamera(sizes) {
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
      25,
      sizes.width / sizes.height,
      0.01,
      5000,
    );

    this.scene.add(camera);
    this.camera = camera;
  }

  _setupControls(camera, canvas) {
    const control = new OrbitControls(camera, canvas);

    control.enableDamping = true;

    this.control = control;
  }

  _render(canvas, sizes) {
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGL1Renderer({
      canvas,
      antialias: true,
      alpha: true,
    });

    renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 0);
    renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height);
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);

    this.renderer = renderer;
  }

  _tick(sizes) {
    this.camera.position.z = 400;
    this.scene.add(this._textGroup);
  
    this._textGeometry.setFromPoints(this._textVertices);

    const colours = [];

    this._textVertices.forEach((vector) => {
      colours.push(vector.r, vector.g, vector.b);
    });
    this._textGeometry.setAttribute(
      "customColor",
      new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(colours, 3),
    );

    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    this.control.update();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(this._tick.bind(this, sizes));
  }

  _resize() {
    const width = window.innerWidth;
    const height = window.innerHeight;

    this.camera.aspect = width / height;
    this.camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    this.renderer.setSize(width, height);
    this.renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2));
  }

  _mousemove(event) {
    // ...
  }
}

export default WebGLCanvas;
```

Comment: can you prepare something in codepen.io or provide a runtime in any way?

Comment: I solved this problem. https://discourse.threejs.org/t/calculate-position-of-object-based-on-center/16990 This page helped me. I deleted my url. Thank you!